# Manipulate MongoDB results to dynamically generate field names

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to restructure the results of Mongo query to use a value from a property call 'field' as the key in the results.

I have a query that returns me results like this:

```
[
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544ecbf11972fd515fd6306c"),
    "field" : "fieldOne",
    "value" : "fieldOneValue"
},
 "_id" : ObjectId("544ecbf11972fd515fd6307c"),
    "field" : "fieldTwo",
    "value" : "fieldTwoValue",
},
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("544ecbf11972fd515fd6308c"),
    "field" : "fieldThree",
    "value" : "fieldThreeValue"
}
]
```

Is there a way to get results like this:

```
{
   fieldOne:fieldOneValue,
   fieldTwo:fieldTwoValue,
   fieldThree:fieldThreeValue
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what your point here is. Sure there are three documents and a single result with the three different values in this case. But what's the point? What is the general aggregation rule for more than one occurrence? The answer to simply solving the above is trivial, but not very useful. You generally just want to keep the data pattern rather than change it. Data points as keys is never a great idea.

Comment: The purpose of this is to run a query and then stream to csv where the field name is the column header. Another useful purpose is to display the data in a grid horizontally instead of vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this with mapReduce, as basically you need the JavaScript processing for dynamic key generation.

Mapping is quite trivial:

```js
var mapper = function () {
  var obj = {};

  obj[this.field] = this.value;
  emit(1,obj);
};
```

And the reducer just combines all elements emitted with the same "key" value:

```js
var reducer = function (key,values) {

  var reduced = {};

  values.forEach(function(value) {
    Object.keys( value ).forEach(function(key) {
      reduced[key] = value[key];
    });
  });

  return reduced;

};
```

Simply call and get the results, albeit in a very "mapReduce" way, since that is how the output always comes:

```js
db.threedocs.mapReduce(mapper,reducer,{ out: { inline: 1 } })
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "value" : {
                            "fieldOne" : "fieldOneValue",
                            "fieldTwo" : "fieldTwoValue",
                            "fieldThree" : "fieldThreeValue"
                    }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 6,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3,
            "emit" : 3,
            "reduce" : 1,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The aggregation framework can get a little closer to nicer output, but can only deal with static data and cannot "dynamically" assign unknown key names. But if you know what to expect you can do this:

```js
db.threedocs.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "fieldOne": {
            "$max": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$field", "fieldOne" ] },
                   "$value",
                   0
               ]
            }
        },
        "fieldTwo": {
            "$max": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$field", "fieldTwo" ] },
                   "$value",
                   0
               ]
            }
        },
        "fieldThree": {
            "$max": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ "$field", "fieldThree" ] },
                   "$value",
                   0
               ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "fieldOne": 1,
        "fieldTwo": 1,
        "fieldThree": 1
    }}
])
```

And the output is nicer:

```js
{
    "fieldOne" : "fieldOneValue",
    "fieldTwo" : "fieldTwoValue",
    "fieldThree" : "fieldThreeValue"
}
```

In either case, the operations are fairly trivial and don't really take into account the presence of multiple values for a "field" or what to do with them. In real world aggregation terms, it is best to stick with the presented data pattern rather than try to represent "data points" as "keys" as this basically asks. But it is impossible to determine from such a sample just what the real intended usage is.

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB 4.4 (didn't check previous versions):

```
db.coll.aggregate($project: {
  $arrayToObject:
      {$map:
        {
          input: "$arrayToParse",
          as: "this",
          in: {
            "k":"$$this.field",
            "v":"$$this.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
)
```